# Скажите правильно я понял функцию copy

Tags: javascript

```js
var vasya = {
  age: 21,
  name: 'Вася',
  surname: 'Петров'
};

var user = {
  isAdmin: false,
  isEmailConfirmed: true
};

var student = {
  university: 'My university'
};

function copy() {
  var dst = arguments[0];

  for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    var arg = arguments[i];
    for (var key in arg) {
      dst[key] = arg[key];
    }
  }

}

console.log(copy(vasya, user, student));
```

1. Внутри функции copy объявляем переменную dst которой присваиваем первый параметр (объект)
2. В функции все данные хранятся в специальном объекте который называют псевдомассив или коллекцией
3. Создаем цикл такая запись показывает  длину псевдомассива arguments.length
4. Длина псевдомассива arguments.length больше 1 идем в тело цикла
5. Объявляем переменную arg которой присваиваем значение псевдомассива (это будет объект user )
6. Создаем цикл в которой операцией in перебираем объект
7. В переменную key присваивается ключ объекта
8. В переменную arg  которая получила ссылку на vasya  благодаря arguments[1]
9. А что дальше происходит ? Ведь arg[key] означает значение объекта
10. Получается  dst[key] тоже получает значение ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > Получается dst[key] тоже получает значение ?

да, получает

В js есть гораздо более прогрессивные способы копировать объекты

Object.assign()  https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Spread оператор https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Answer (score 0):

Ну вы добавьте `return dst` в `copy`,

увидите что она добавляет в первый объект значения из второго и третьего

```js
var vasya = {
  age: 21,
  name: 'Вася',
  surname: 'Петров'
};

var user = {
  isAdmin: false,
  isEmailConfirmed: true
};

var student = {
  university: 'My university'
};

function copy() {
  var dst = arguments[0];

  for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    var arg = arguments[i];
    for (var key in arg) {
      dst[key] = arg[key];
    }
  }
   return dst
}

console.log(copy(vasya, user, student));
```

```
{
    "age": 21,
    "name": "Вася",
    "surname": "Петров",
    "isAdmin": false,
    "isEmailConfirmed": true,
    "university": "My university"
}
```